# How to Upgrade TLS to the last version on Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, setup, tls

I came from this thread [TLS Upgrade on Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204399/tls-upgrade-on-marketing-cloud) where I can see information about the impact of the deprecation of TLS 1.0 but I can't see concise instructions to upgrade TLS on demand.

How could I upgrade TLS on demand? Can I do it from MC? Do I need support or additional services?

Comment: what version do you want to upgrade to? SFMC will negotiate 1.1/1.2

Comment: I don't know yet, I have to get the update from my security team but I wanted to know what the is the process.  Do I have to open a ticket with support? Do I have to call my Account Executive? Also, how can I check the TLS version that I have currently?

Comment: There is nothing to update. Sfmc will connect using 1.1/1.2. So if you only want to connect with 1.2 you should handle that on your side